# substr Error -- ORA-01722:invaild number separate string

Tags: sql, oracle, substr, ora-01722

I am trying to separate first and last name . I have a column called 'Fullname' and it has first and last name and a comma all in one column. I've tried the below but I get an error " its not a valid number". When I remove the comma it works, so I am not sure how to incorporate a comma in the formula so it can work.

,`substr(Fullname,1,',') as Lastname`
,`substr(Fullname,',','  ') as Firstname`

```
Column 

Fullname
Brown,John N
Green,Julie T


Desired results
Lastname    FirstName
Brown        John
Green        Julie
```

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd arguments to `substr()` must be numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(name, '[^,]+', 1, 1) as lastname,
       regexp_substr(name, '[^, ]+', 1, 2) as firstname
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked ! I am going to have study up on regexp_substr .. Thanks again .

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `SUBSTR()` is the position of the substring, the third argument is the length of the substring. It will not automatically search for a delimiter if you use strings there instead of numbers. You can use `LOCATE()` to find the positions that you want.

```
SUBSTR(Fullname, 1, LOCATE(Fullname, ',')-1) AS Lastname,
SUBSTR(Fullname, LOCATE(Fullname, ',')+1) AS Firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be performed in Classical way by using `instr` inside `substr` function as the following case :

```
select substr(fullname,1,instr(fullname,',')-1) Firstname,
       substr(fullname,instr(fullname,',')+1,length(fullname)) Lastname
  from tab;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8fe9/1)